# Troubles with "modal_dialog" in ROR bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I use gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", and follow the official steps to install it.

But modal_dialog helper give me very specific result -

```
<%= modal_dialog id: "modal",
             header: {  dismiss: 'modal', title: 'Modal header' },
             body:   { content: 'This is the body' },
             footer: { content: content_tag(:button, 'Save', class: 'btn') } %>
```

[image: helper in work ...]

It's need to notice, if I copy/paste modal snippet from TWB site it worked fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modal_dialog method seems to be broken in twitter-bootstrap-rails v3.2.0.

Try 3.2.1.rc1.